# Posting comment in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I'm making a sample app (blog app), but I'm stuck trying to visualize the comment a of post, just I saw the created date.

using RailInstaller 3.0.0
rails -v 4.1.4
ruby -v 2.0.0p195
running in Windows 7

**app/views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
> <h1><%= @post.titulo %></h1> 
> <p><%= @post.texto %></p>
> 
> <h2>Comentarios</h2> 
> <% @post.comentarios.each do |comentario| %>
> <p><%= comentario.texto %></p>    
> <p><%= time_ago_in_words comentario.created_at %> atras</p>
> <% end %>
> 
> <%= form_for [@post, @post.comentarios.build] do |f| %>       
> <%= f.text_area :texto %></br>        
> <%= f.submit 'Comenta' %> 
> <% end %>
> 
> <p>
> <%= link_to 'Atras', posts_path %>
> |
> <%= link_to 'Editar',edit_post_path(@post) %>
> | 
> <%= link_to 'Borrar', @post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Estás seguro?' } %>
> </p>
```

**app/controllers/comentarios_controller.rb**

> ```
> class ComentariosController < ApplicationController
>   def create
>       @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
>       @comentario = @post.comentarios.build(params[:comentarios])
>       @comentario.save
>
>       redirect_to @post
>   end
>
>   def destroy
>   end
> end
> ```

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in rails 4, you have to permit your params in your controller with:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comentario = @post.comentarios.build(comment_params)
  @comentario.save

  redirect_to @post
end

private

def comment_params
  params.require(:comentario).permit(:texto)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that `texto` is not actually getting saved anything in attributes of `comentarios`. You can cross check my words by checking `comentarios` table in your database.

In rails 4, you need to permit attributes.

In your controller, you can do like:

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController
  def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @post.comentarios.create(comentario_params)

      redirect_to @post
  end

  ...
  ...

  private

  def comentario_params
    params.require(:comentario).permit(:texto)
  end
end
```

Magic! you can see `texto` on `show` page now..!!

Comment: is my second week learning ruby, and learning any language :)